# How to select the parameters in Sampling Function while implementing Variational Auto-Encoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, autoencoder

I'm currently trying to implement a Variational Auto-Encoder to later use the Encoder half of the model for classification but it seems like changing the parameters inside the sampling function which is the follows

```
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(tf.keras.backend.shape(z_mean)[0], 19), mean=0., stddev=1.)
    return z_mean + tf.keras.backend.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

The initial stddev was 1. which was used in various website is giving an accuracy of

```
175/175 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6856 - accuracy: 0.5614
Train accuracy: 56.14%
```

But when i used a different stddev 0.003 which my friend recommended the accuracy has increased to

```
175/175 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3329 - accuracy: 0.8598
Train accuracy: 85.98%
```

What exactly is happening here and how do i decide the parameters for this.

p.s if you want to check the whole code https://github.com/midnightripper/accuracy_improvement/blob/main/vae_with_split.ipynb

I tried using the std-dev that everyone else was implementing while using the variational auto-encoder code but it seems that it affects the accuracy of the model

Answer (score 1):

In this case this standard deviation should not be changed like that, otherwise you are not sampling correctly from a Normal(z_mean, z_variance).

By using a very small standard deviation of 0.003 you made it "sample" very close to the mean. Basically you are encouraging the network to be an identity function and only repeat the input, so accuracy seems to be better but the network becomes useless as a feature extractor for your future classification task.

Comment: so what could i do to increase the test accuracy, like the model sampling using variance 1 is giving a very bad accuracy

Comment: There is too little information to draw out a conclusion, I suggest investigating deeper what kind of mistakes the model is making. How does the predicted compare to the original data? What patterns can you see there? Then you can formulate a hypothesis of why the accuracy is low, and then you can start to look for a way to improve that.

Comment: I used T-SNE plot to check if the model is able to extract features well but it seems that encoder is doing much worse, I created another thread about this please check    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76053634/how-to-implement-a-good-vae-for-feature-extraction