# How to Implement a good VAE for Feature Extraction

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, tsne

I'm currently working on a VAE and trying to use the encoder half for feature extraction,but it seems like it's giving a worse accuracy when training my model, when i'm trying to implement T-SNE graph to know how well it's embedding it seems like it's only doing worse for the dataset
The code:

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='input')
x = keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu')(inputs)
z_mean = keras.layers.Dense(8, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = keras.layers.Dense(8, name='z_log_var')(x)
z = keras.layers.Lambda(sampling, name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()
```

```
latent_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(8), name='z_sampling')
x = keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(19, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
```

```
encoder = Model(inputs, z_mean)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, outputs)
reconstruction_loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(inputs, outputs)
reconstruction_loss = reconstruction_loss * 19

# KL Divergence loss
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
vae_loss = tf.reduce_mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)

autoencoder.add_loss(vae_loss)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam')
autoencoder.summary()
autoencoder.fit(x_train, epochs=50, batch_size=265, validation_data=(x_test, None))
```

```
# encoded_data = encoder.predict(x_train)
# print(encoded_data.shape)
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, random_state=123)
z = tsne.fit_transform(x_train)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["y"] = y_train
df["comp-1"] = z[:,0]
df["comp-2"] = z[:,1]

sns.scatterplot(x="comp-1", y="comp-2", hue=df.y.tolist(),
                palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 10),
                data=df).set(title="Encoder T-SNE projection")
```

Here's the original T-SNE Plot for the implementation
[image: This is the original T-SNE plot]

```
encoded_data = encoder.predict(x_train)
print(encoded_data.shape)
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, random_state=123)
z = tsne.fit_transform(encoded_data)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["y"] = y_train
df["comp-1"] = z[:,0]
df["comp-2"] = z[:,1]

sns.scatterplot(x="comp-1", y="comp-2", hue=df.y.tolist(),
                palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 10),
                data=df).set(title="MNIST data T-SNE projection")
```

This is the encoder T-SNE plot using the above code
[image: This is for the encoder]

It seems the representation only got worse so is the accuracy of the model what should i do to improve the representation or cluster it better.

[Here's the entire code](https://github.com/midnightripper/accuracy_improvement/blob/main/Variational_Auto_Encoder.ipynb)

I tried many different types of VAE first i thought the  accuracy diminished since i used a std-dev as 1 and replaced it with 0.004 but it seems that it would make model learn no features. So when i tried to change the pipeline of the Variational AutoEncoder it seems the bottleneck is not learning good features when i learnt to use t-sne.
Please help me in this, Thank you